# tree /f cmd with date modified. Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, tree

I need to create a "`tree` list" of a drive its folders, subfolders, and the date modified.

`tree /f` command works great but I need to add the date modified.

How can I do that?

Comment: `gci c:\ -dir  -r | select FullName, LastWriteTime`

Comment: This is a really good start. It would be awesome if I could display it like a tree or or hierarchy that physically indicates folders, sub folders, and documents. Is this possible?

Comment: Adopted from [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Tree/1.0.0/Content/Show-Tree.ps1): `gci c:\ -r |  select @{n="name";e={"{0}+---{1}" -f ("| " * ($_.fullname -split "\\").Count), $_.Name}}, Attributes, LastWriteTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be as pretty, but you can use the `-Recurse` option with Get-ChildItem to find all of this (Plus you could create an object out of it and have a lot more fun).

```
$Path = Path/To/Directory
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse
```

Your output will look something like this:

```
    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/21/2018   3:13 PM                subdir1
-a----        5/10/2018   2:48 PM             59 script.ps1


    Directory: C:\Temp\subdir1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        5/21/2018   3:13 PM              0 test.txt
```

Comment: That format looks good but it comes out as an error when I enter that code into powershell.

Comment: What error?  Did you use a full path to set up the $Path variable (such as `$Path = C:\Temp\MyDir`

Comment: I got it! Thanks, my mistake.

Comment: Good!  Feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as correct by hitting the green checkbox to the left of the arrows.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald is there an easy method to export the results to a txt file?

Answer (score 1):

- With the [PowerShell Community Extensions (pscx)](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) comes a `Show-Tree`
  cmdlet
- which has a `-ShowProperty` parameter which shows all properties
- these can be reduced with an `-ExcludeProperty` parameter

---

```
> Show-Tree c:\test -ShowLeaf -ShowProperty -Excludeproperty $Exclude
C:\test
|--Property: LastWriteTime = 05/12/2018 21:40:57
|--2018
|  |--Property: LastWriteTime = 04/10/2018 19:00:47
|  \--04
|     |--Property: LastWriteTime = 04/10/2018 19:00:47
|     \--10
|        \--Property: LastWriteTime = 04/10/2018 19:00:47
```

To prettify this output (LastWriteTime prepended on the same line)
this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\21\SO_50469606.ps1
$Exclude = ("Attributes","BaseName","CreationTime","CreationTimeUtc","Exists",
            "Extension","FullName","LastAccessTime","LastAccessTimeUtc",
            "LastWriteTimeUtc","LinkType","Mode","Parent","ReparsePoint","Root",
            "Target","Directory","DirectoryName","IsReadOnly","Length","VersionInfo")

$BaseDir = 'c:\test'
(Show-Tree $BaseDir -ShowLeaf -ShowProperty -ExcludeProperty $Exclude -IndentSize 4|
out-string) -replace '([a-z]?:?[\\\|\- ]+.*?)\r?\n.*Property: LastWriteTime = ([0-9\/\.: \-]+)','$2 $1'
```

returns this sample output:

```
05/12/2018 21:40:57 C:\test
04/10/2018 19:00:47 |---2018
04/10/2018 19:00:47 |   \---04
04/10/2018 19:00:47 |       \---10
05/17/2018 16:01:17 |---folder1
05/17/2018 16:01:17 |   \---blah.txt
04/27/2018 23:40:27 |---folder2
04/27/2018 23:40:27 |---folder3
03/29/2018 15:37:15 |---subdir0
03/29/2018 15:37:15 |---subdir1
03/29/2018 15:41:55 |---subdir2
03/29/2018 15:41:34 |   \---20180329154134,19.txt
03/29/2018 15:37:15 |---subdir3
03/29/2018 15:42:11 \---subdir4
03/29/2018 15:42:05     |---20180329154205,27.txt
03/29/2018 15:42:11     \---20180329154211,87.txt
```