# In powershell: Looking to get files and folders in a tree like manner- outputting last write time

Tags: file, powershell, directory

I can do one or the other with

```
get-childitem c:\locationhere -rec | where {$_.PSIsContainer} |
select-object FullName, LastWriteTime | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path C:\file.csv
```

the `{!$_.PSIsContainer}`    with the exclamation gets me just files.  Without gets me just folders.  Any to get them all ?  I appreciate any help.  I'm stuck.
Thank you

Comment: Take that bit out altogether and you will get files and folders

Comment: What you're doing there is "Get me all the folders", or "get me everything that isn't a folder!"  Like @EBGreen said, removing it will get you both.

Comment: The output will look jagged due to usually different file name length, so I'd reverse the properties. If using the pscx cmdlet `Show-Tree` you can tweak and massage the output like I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472313/6811411)